# Modify VS2015 project so it opens in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a WIndows Forms project in two PCs: one has VS2010 and the other one VS2015.

When I'm working on the VS2010 project and copy the project to the VS2015 PC, everything's fine since VS2015 will open the project without problems.

On the other hand, I have issues when trying to open the project in VS2010 after working on it in VS2015.

Is there a way I can "save as" in my VS2015 so I can open it in VS2010?

In terms of moving the project around, I just copy it to a memory stick, replace the folder in the PC I'll be working in, and then open the project in Visual Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: Define "issues". I checked just now and don't have any such issues.

Comment: There is no such feature.  Just take advantage of the VS2015 license rights.  You can install it on any machine as long as you don't use them at the same time.

Comment: @zeromus, the issue is that VS2010 can't open a project that was created in a newer version of VS. Also, the VS2015 machine has Windows 10 while the VS2010 machine has Win7.

Comment: Define "can't open". I switch between vs2010 and vs2015 a thousand times a day. There are a variety of things that go wrong, but you won't tell us what's going wrong.